# Not show JavaFx window in my project

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I created a JavaFx project.

I designed the window in scene builder but it does not show my design. It shows me a blank window.

What is the problem?

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    this.PrimaryStage = primaryStage;
    MainWindow();
}

public void MainWindow() throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("MainWindowView.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = loader.load();
        MainWindowsController mainWindowsController = loader.getController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        PrimaryStage.setScene(scene);
        PrimaryStage.show();

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

I designed this:

[image: desdign]

but when I run the project it shows me this:

[image: run]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainWindowsController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="label" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="78.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="43.0" text="Label" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-1.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="34.0" />
         </font></Label>
      <HBox fx:id="fild" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="192.0" layoutY="232.0" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="192.0" layoutY="232.0" />
            <Button layoutX="386.0" layoutY="232.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: probably you haven't set width and height of window.

Comment: no . it show me the window but no show the elemet

Comment: Sometimes Netbeans seems to take a while to refresh the fxml in the classpath with the new version. Try *Clean & Build*. BTW: you shouldn't specify `layoutX` and `layoutY` for managed `Node`s inside a `Parent` that sets the positions of it's children itself...